# Non-existence of countable sigma-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

**Question** Does there exists an infinite $\sigma$-algebra which has only countably many members?

---

**Solution** Let $\mathcal{A} = \{A_1, A_2, \dots \}$ be the countable $\sigma$-algebra of $X$.

Define the equivalence relation $x \sim y \iff (x \in A_i \leftrightarrow y \in A_i)$. Then $X / \sim$ is a set of *distinguishable* elements of $X$. $X / \sim$ is at least countable, because otherwise $\mathcal{A}$ will be finite.

For every distinct $x, y \in X/\sim$, there exists $A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $x \subset A, y \not\subset A$. Then because $\mathcal{A}$ is countable, we can construct every $x \in X/\sim$ with countable number of substitution.

Let $Y$ be the countable subset of $X/\sim$. $Y \subset \mathcal{A}$ and $Y$ is countable, so the uncountable set $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ lies inside $\mathcal{A}$ which leads to contradiction.

---

How does it look? If it is wrong, can it be fixed with minor changes? Or is it completely wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $Y \subset \mathcal A$ does not make sense.

Comment: What does "we can construct every $x \in X/{\sim}$ with countable number of substitution" mean?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Yes it is.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I meant that for fixed $x \in X/\sim$, and every $y$ distinct with $x$, there exists $A_y \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $x \subset A_y, y \not\subset A_y$, and we can get $\{x\}$ by intersection of them.